I am facing an issue while trying to install TensorFlow on my Windows 10 machine with Python 3.12.0. Despite I keep receiving the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shash\Music\New folder\tensorflow001.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
  File "C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.``

I have Tried the following:
updated pip
reinstalled tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu
downgraded python to 3.10
install tensorflow using conda
and a few more thing i dont remeber

Hi @Shashank  , the error you are facing shows that tensorflow can’t find or load certain dynamic libraries that are required for proper functioning. Makesure you are using compatible version of Python and Tensorflow. Second point is there are some incompatible or missing dynamic libraries stop you code to run properly  and check your GPU Drive version ensure that diver are up-to-date.If possible create new  virtual environment then try.
